# ROS2 launch FindPackageShare vs get_package_share_directory

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed 2 possible ways to get the `share` directory of a package from within a `launch.py` file:

```
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

get_package_share_directory("package_a")
```

versus

```
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

FindPackageShare("package_a")
```

The former returns a string directly, the latter will be evaluated to a string when passed into a `LaunchDescription` somewhere.

Which one is recommended?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354633/ros2-launch-findpackageshare-vs-get_package_share_directory/) by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-06-11

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Interesting - I suppose the launch_ros.substitutions is the preferred since somebody spent the time to implement it - and under the hood it actually just calls ament_index_python.packages.get_package_shared_directory (see https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/pull/57/files#diff-a386f24e1ed85582db84abc87a5bf684R100)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on 2020-06-12**:
That's what I found already as well, but no recommendation to use one or the other...